# Calculate percentile for data in csv file with Linux tools

Tags: csv, awk

I have a file that is formated as follows:

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label
2020/07/08 19:54:44.327,1395,Method1
2020/07/08 19:54:44.327,1395,Method1
2020/07/08 19:54:44.327,1396,Method1
2020/07/08 19:54:44.327,1396,Method1
2020/07/08 19:54:44.327,1406,Method1
2020/07/08 19:54:44.327,1406,Method1
2020/07/08 19:54:44.327,1456,Method1
2020/07/08 19:54:44.327,1456,Method1
2020/07/08 19:54:48.618,1403,Method2
2020/07/08 19:54:48.618,1403,Method2
2020/07/08 19:54:48.618,1203,Method2
2020/07/08 19:54:48.618,1102,Method2
2020/07/08 19:54:48.618,1203,Method3
2020/07/08 19:54:48.618,1403,Method3
2020/07/08 19:54:48.618,1603,Method3
2020/07/08 19:54:48.618,1401,Method3
```

I want to calculate the percentiles of the column "elapsed" for each unique entry in the last column.
With Excel I would use the following formula:

```
=PERCENTILE.INC(IF($C:$C=S2;$B:$B);0,9)
```

So something like this:

[image]

I am trying to achieve the same inside my linux server, so that I don't have to use Excel and can automate this process.

I have tried it with AWK but without much success.
My attempts include

```
awk -F',' '{print $3, $2}' data.csv | sort | awk 'BEGIN{i=0} {s[i]=$0; i++;} END{print s[int(NR*0.95-0.5)]}'
output: Method3 1401

awk -F',' '{print $3, $2}' data.csv | awk '{all[NR] = $0} END{print all[int(NR*0.90 - 0.5)]}'
output: 1403d3
```

But both of these would only get me values for one line and they are different from the values i get in Excel. As far as I can see it always returns the last line of the file.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? Or explain what part I am missing to accomplish this.

EDIT:
The expected outcome that I want to achieve is:

```
Method1,1456
Method2,1403
Method3,1543

Or additionally including count

Method1,1456,8
Method2,1403,4
Method3,1543,4
```

Comment: please add the sample output you expect from the existing sample input.

Comment: I have added an expected outcome. Sorry for not including it initially

Comment: Please add what's the percentile you want. From the image it seems to be  the 90th percentile. Please write it in the text

Comment: Yes it is 90 percentile.

Comment: @nixpix unfortunately the question is closed and I cannot add my reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [GNU `datamash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
$ datamash -H -t, -g3 perc:90 2 count 3 < input.txt
GroupBy(label),perc:90(elapsed),count(label)
Method1,1456,8
Method2,1403,4
Method3,1543,4
```

Does require that the input is sorted on the third, grouped-by column like your example - if not, add the `-s` option to sort it for you.

Comment: I am accepting this answer since it is the easiest to implement and I can freely install utilities on my machine. For people who cannot do this the other answers are more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any expected output or an algorithm to use to calculate whatever percentiles you want so idk what exactly you want to calculate but here's how to collect and loop through the data:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR == 1 { next }
{ curr = $3 }
curr != prev {
    if (prev != "") {
        prt()
    }
    prev = curr
}
{ vals[++numVals] = $2 }
END { prt() }

function prt(    valNr) {
    print prev, numVals
    for (valNr=1; valNr<=numVals; valNr++) {
        print "\t" vals[valNr]
    }
    delete vals
    numVals = 0
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Method1,8
        1395
        1395
        1396
        1396
        1406
        1406
        1456
        1456
Method2,4
        1403
        1403
        1203
        1102
Method3,4
        1203
        1403
        1603
        1401
```

I expect given that you can do whatever calculation you have in mind using the values for each label within the `prt()` function.

Answer (score 1):

not sure about your algorithm, but linear interpolation gives a different result for Method3 data

```
$ sort -t, -k3 file | 
  awk -F, -v OFS=, '{k=$3} 
               NR>1 {a[k,++c[k]]=$2} 
                END {print "Label","TTLB","Count"; 
                     for(k in c) 
                       {t=c[k]*0.9; 
                        ti=int(t); 
                        print k,a[k,ti]*(1-t+ti)+a[k,ti+1]*(t-ti),c[k]}}'

Label,TTLB,Count
Method1,1456,8
Method2,1403,4
Method3,1523,4
```

Most likely it's not just a linear interpolation between the closes data end points, but not sure what Excel uses.